# Not able to get response back on java code while http get with S60

Tags: symbian, java-me, s60

I am using Net Beans for developing an application on S60. I made one page for user authentication and using .net wcf service to authenticate user. i am able to send data on .net service by HttpGet method but not able to get response back on java page.

I have tested it on fiddler with this url its working fine and returning response code 200, but not getting response code by java code. Following code i am using. Is some thing wrong here ?

```
httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
"Profile/MIDP-2.1 Confirguration/CLDC-1.1");

int respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Are you saying that getResponseCode() never returns?

Comment: I am not able to get control back on the line "int respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();" from web server.

Comment: can you still run a completely separate java thread while getResponseCode() is blocked? something that doesn't use any kind of GCF API. update a Canvas on the screen or a RecordStore.

Comment: Hi QuickRecipesOnSymbianOS, i am new in j2me development i didnt get how can i do it. basically my whole scenario is as given:-when I debug "httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);" line.It asks me for allow connection for this session on s60 simulator, after allowing, control is on "int respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();" line and asks for connection with IIS server by 1 access point "winsock", after connect control goes on wcf service but never come back on client side/java page.

Answer (score 0):

try user agent "Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1"

Comment: this is just a get http request.
i will suggest that use this url on your mobile web browser and see the result. sometimes in organizations, admin blocks the requests from other user agents.

Comment: Please give me the url where i can achive the response from iis server.